# How do I fix a Java:26: error: No suitable constructor found

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm pretty new to Java script writing and I'm trying to fix four errors I get when I compile my code. I'm so frustrated, what am I doing wrong?

The Errors are:

```
SavingsAccount.java:25: error: no suitable constructor found for BankAccount(String,double,double)
super(name, balance, interestRate);
^
constructor BankAccount.BankAccount(String,double) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor BankAccount.BankAccount(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
SavingsAccount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
Interest = balance * (interestRate / 12);
^
symbol: variable Interest
location: class SavingsAccount
SavingsAccount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
Interest = balance * (interestRate / 12);
^
symbol: variable interestRate
location: class SavingsAccount
SavingsAccount.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
this.deposit(interest);
^
symbol: variable interest
location: class SavingsAccount
4 errors
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner class
import java.text.DecimalFormat; // Needed for 2 decimal place amounts
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    static {
        BankAccount account; // To reference a BankAccount object
        double balance, // The account's starting balance
        interestRate; // The annual interest rate
        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Create an object for dollars and cents
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        // Get the starting balance.
        // Get the annual interest rate.
        interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble() * .001;
        // post monthly interest by multiplying current balance
        // by current interest rate divided by 12 and then adding
        // result to balance by making deposit
    }

    public SavingsAccount(String name, double balance, double interestRate)
            throws NegativeAmountException {
        super(name, balance, interestRate);
    }

    public void postInterest() {
        Interest = balance * (interestRate / 12);
        try {
            this.deposit(interest);
            // and current account balance (use printStatement from
            // the BankAccount superclass)
            // following this also print current interest rate
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SavingsAccount.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

BankAccount.java (This one works with no errors):

```
class BankAccount {
    public String name;
    public double balance;

    public BankAccount(String name, double balance) throws NegativeAmountException {
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance; // set name and balance 
        if (balance < 0) { // make sure balance is not negative
            throw new NegativeAmountException("Can not create an account with a negative amount."); // throw exception if balance is negative
        }
    }

    public BankAccount(String name) throws NegativeAmountException {
        this(name, 0); // set name and use 0 balance 
    }

    // update balance by adding deposit amount
    // make sure deposit amount is not negative 
    // throw exception if deposit is negative 
    public void deposit(double amount) throws NegativeAmountException {
        if (amount > 0) {
            this.balance += amount;
        }
        else {
            throw new NegativeAmountException("Deposit amount must not be negative");
        }
    }

    // update balance by subtracting withdrawal amount
    // throw exception if funds are not sufficient
    // make sure withdrawal amount is not negative 
    // throw NegativeAmountException if amount is negative 
    // throw InsufficientFundsException if balance < amount
    public void withdraw(double amount) throws InsufficientFundsException, NegativeAmountException {
        if (amount > getBalance()) {
            throw new InsufficientFundsException("You do not have sufficient funds for this operation.");
        }
        else if (amount < 0) {
            throw new NegativeAmountException("Withdrawal amount must not be negative.");
        }
        else {
            this.balance -= amount;
        }
    }

    // return current balance
    public double getBalance() {
        return this.balance;
    }

    // print bank statement including customer name
    // and current account balance
    public void printStatement() {
        System.out.println("Balance for " + this.name + ": " + getBalance());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript here.

Comment: Looks like this is java not javascript. Can you include your BankAccount class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors in code:

About first error Java compiler notes that in superclass `BankAccount` you haven't constructor with 3 variables (your call `super(name, balance, interestRate);` in `SavingAccounts` class. You should:

- add corresponding constructor to `BankAccount` class or
- use existent constructor from `BankAccount` class and keep `interestRate` as `SavingAccounts` class variable.

Second error makes 3 error by compiler opinion: in code `Interest = balance * (interestRate / 12);` you lost local variable. After fix it (seems that should be `double interest = balance * (interestRate / 12);`) you'll remove 3 errors.

Comment: Where exactly should I add the constructor to the BankAccount? Sorry still trying to get the hang of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

You normally do not use a `static` block as you do. You may want to write a `public static void main(String... args)`.

The actual problem with your code is the superclass-constructor call via `super(...)`. `BankAccount` does not provide an accessible constructor with the specified signature (`String, double, double`). Either there is no such constructor or the constructor is not visible (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for details).
For the other errors regarding `Interest`, please look at [Pavel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097656/4216641).

Furthermore, there are some general accepted coding standards for Java, some can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Please respect them.